# Getting an error when using msal in a nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I downloaded the sample code [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps) for Web Applications (NodeJs) and replace the config parameters with my application's values. Like this:

```
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "12345678901234567890",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/09876543210987654321",
        clientSecret: "*****************",
        knownAuthorities: ["https://login.microsoftonline.com/09876543210987654321"
    ]
    },
```

When I run the App I get the following:

```
[Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:30:24 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.0.0 : Info - getAuthCodeUrl called
[Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:30:24 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.0.0 : Verbose - initializeRequestScopes called
[Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:30:24 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.0.0 : Verbose - buildOauthClientConfiguration called
[Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:30:24 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.0.0 : Verbose - createAuthority called
[Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:30:24 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.0.0 : Verbose - Retrieving all cache keys
[Wed, 17 Mar 2021 17:30:24 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-node@1.0.0 : Verbose - Getting cache key-value store
{"errorCode":"endpoints_resolution_error","errorMessage":"Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints. Check your authority and verify the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns the required endpoints. Attempted to retrieve endpoints from: https://login.microsoftonline.com/09876543210987654321/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration","subError":"","name":"ClientAuthError"}
```

I don't know why I get the error, I'm not connected to a VPN or using a Proxy just to my regular ISP.

Comment: Hi Jason, the problem is that I cannot change those settings because they set for my organization.

Comment: The correct step is like this. If you don't have permission to set it, there should be no way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Make sure you have configured the following settings on the portal.**

---

## Tips

***If my solution does not take effect, please open the browser in privacy mode and try it to eliminate the factor of browser caching. If it still does not work, refresh it a few times.***

---

[image]

[image]

## **Code in my project**

index.js file.

```
auth: {
    clientId: "clientID",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID",
    clientSecret: "yoursecret",
    knownAuthorities: ["https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID"]
},
```

[image]

***It works for me.***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with a self-signed certificate. My application tried to call '.well-known/openid-configuration' GET endpoint but it was blocked. The workaround was to add "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED": "0" to my environmental variables.